# Demodulating FM from IQ Samples using Simulink

Tags: matlab, audio

I am using simulink and have got IQ samples from an RTL-2832 / E4000 usb dongle. I would like to learn how to decode an FM station to audio and attempt this project on simulink. How do I proceed with the IQ Samples towards decoding?

Treat this a  question from a DSP novice.

Comment: I have managed to do this using GNURadio, but it had a block WFMDecoder or something. On Simulink, I did a bandpass filter on the IQ samples. squared and rooted it to get a real signal. Tried to mix it with a locally generated carrier and could display a few things on the scope, but nothing made much sense.

Comment: after search over google, this link http://www.chrec.org/pubs/MILCOM09_B1.pdf looks related to your problem. Given two method will demodulate the FM signal, and later you have process it further to separate L and R channel.